# How do I change application language?

Tags: android, localization

How to change language of an application from app setting?

I want my app to support three languages: Spanish, Portuguese and English and give an option to select the language from the settings menu of my app.

Comment: be cereful with action bar titles [make multi language android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727543/make-multi-language-android-application/40302562#40302562)

Answer (score 1):

Using following class you can change language from application.

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static void onCreate(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static void onCreate(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static void setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);
        updateResources(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private static void updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        android.content.res.Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, dm);

    }
}
```

call language change using following object.

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(getBaseContext(), "ar");
```

Please do not forgot to refresh current activity after call this. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Implementing Localization is your solution

Create seperate values folder for each language and android os will automatically select corresponding values based on locale on ur device

Please follow steps [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/10/android-localization-tutorial-with.html?m=1

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_localization.htm