# Android, different languages

Tags: android, localization

Is it possible to make Android app using language which is chosen by click on some of few buttons? For example, if I have four buttons on beginning of an app, with text: "english", "german", "italiano", "español", I want to use german language in an app when I click on button "german". I know I have to use different folders for strings(values-de for german), but I don't know how and where to change default setting which uses default folder for values.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make multi language android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727543/make-multi-language-android-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override **attachBaseContext** method in every class. and pass the selected locale code to super method. The below code is used in Kotlin

```
 override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    val lang = SharedPref.getPrefVal<String>(newBase, Constants.SELECTED_LANG_CODE)
    super.attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase, lang))
}
```

**MyContextWrapper** class to support language change in all versions

```
public class MyContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {

public MyContextWrapper(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context, String language) {
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale sysLocale = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        sysLocale = getSystemLocale(config);
    } else {
        sysLocale = getSystemLocaleLegacy(config);
    }
    if (!language.equals("") && !sysLocale.getLanguage().equals(language)) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            setSystemLocale(config, locale);
        } else {
            setSystemLocaleLegacy(config, locale);
        }

    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
    } else {
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return new MyContextWrapper(context);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Locale getSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config) {
    return config.locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static Locale getSystemLocale(Configuration config) {
    return config.getLocales().get(0);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void setSystemLocaleLegacy(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
    config.locale = locale;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static void setSystemLocale(Configuration config, Locale locale) {
    config.setLocale(locale);
}
}
```

and while setting the language in onClick method use:

```
 try {                           
     attachBaseContext(MyContextWrapper.wrap(applicationContext, lang_code))
     } catch (e: Exception) {
     }
```

Let me know if you need any help to understand the code structure

Comment: I have never used Kotlin, I'm using Java, but I suppose that the structure of code is similar?

Comment: will this work on androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code.**

for language change i made one function you have to pass language code and context.

language="en" set language as per your requirement(English en, French fr, Spanish sp & [Other Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7989085/5995648)) context pass your activity/fragment context

```
    public static boolean setLangRecreate(String language, Context context) {
try {
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    // recreate();
    ((Activity) context).finish();
    ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    ((Activity) context).startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
    ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return false;}
```